Problems building dmlc on Windows
I am learning about simics, now I am trying to build dmlc on a test project and following the guide on github, on the step "Building DMLC from a Simics project" using the command bin\make dmlc throws an error that bin could not be loaded.

Have been some days on research to find that and just found that I had to install "MinGW", but its not working, so now its time to ask for help, being new with this technologies make me think I am not going in the correct way.

Solved using winlibs, thank you all for the help

If winlibs worked, please mark that reply as accepted to help others.

Note that there is no need to build DMLC in order to compile DML. A perfectly functioning DMLC is part of the Intel Simics installation.

I meet similar issue. I install Simics simulator public release in WSL2. DMLC can be compiled in that environment.

If there is no bin directory in your project at all, something is really broken. But I guess all that is missing is the make trampoline.
To build with gcc and Make on Windows, you do need to install either MinGW or better, winlibs. That will give you make and gcc and other tools in one single package.
If you put the mingw64 directory from inside winlibs zip file as C:\mingw64, the Make-based build system should find it automatically.  Rerun project-setup, or create a new project.  To see if it finds the toolchain and creates the trampoline, run with -V.  If not, use the --mingw-dir option to the tool to point out the location of the MinGW toolchain.
#Iamintel

If you have reasonably easy access to a Linux machine then I would strongly recommend to do your work there to start with.
Everyone in the DMLC team work almost exclusively from Linux environments. We maintain the Windows build by running regression tests on build servers, so it should work, but you can expect an unpolished development experience.
